# How to create a flexible height background while the sibling is not in the background and retain stacking order

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a Fiddle so I can better explain what I would like to achieve.

https://jsfiddle.net/rgeelen/3cfw1vpx/15/

As you can see the header (title, subtitle, desc) are contained within a background color.

The list is outside of this background color. On small screens, the list will be under its own header.

The problem is to make this possible I kind of create a hacky solution. This solution has a downside. The height of the header background is not flexible and will not scale when the content changes.

```
/* hack for the bg (it's no flexible) */   
  .section::before {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    height: 160px;
    background-color: #252130;
  }
```

I wonder how I can create a good flexible solution. But still retain the behavior (stacking of elements) how it is.

For example, it is possible to do the following. The downside is that the stack order is changed. On small screens, we will get header, header, header, list, list, list.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"><div class="team__head"></div></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><div class="team__head"></div></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><div class="team__head"></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"><div class="team__list"></div></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><div class="team__list"></div></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><div class="team__list"></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to duplicate the content so you hide and show the list at different breakpoints. As you have already found out you cannot get items that are nested to react to how other DOM elements are behaving.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"><div class="team__head"></div><div class="col-md-4 d-none d-md-block"><div class="team__list"></div></div></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><div class="team__head"></div><div class="col-md-4 d-none d-md-block"><div class="team__list"></div></div></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><div class="team__head"></div><div class="col-md-4 d-none d-md-block"><div class="team__list"></div></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container d-md-none">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"><div class="team__list"></div></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><div class="team__list"></div></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><div class="team__list"></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```